# Don't see Dart as language in Android Studio version 4.2.1

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have installed all the plugins, Dart and Flutter specifically.

On the screen after "create new flutter project", there are only two languages shown: Java and Kotlin. That's all. They have changed the UI and it just turned the whole game for beginners like me.

Comment: Where exactly don't you see it? Can you create a new flutter project?

Comment: On the screen after "create new flutter project". There are only two languages shown java and kotlin. That's all. They have changed the UI and it just turned the whole game for beginners like me. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those languages you see are only if you want to write native plugins.

Your Flutter project will always be using Dart. You cannot select it because no choice is possible. It's Dart. Always.

Just continue with the wizard as normal and it will create a Flutter project using Dart.